# jQuery Chosen - Performance and Observer like pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I readed almost every post regarding performance issues with this plugin, my problem is how to get notified when the combo is fully loaded. Im working with 8k+ results and the whole page freezes for a few seconds when loading, thats ok, but it doesnt seem to be an api notifying when it finished loading the results set. I have tried chosen:ready, but it doesnt seem to work the way i need it to do.

Is there an observer like pattern? Can you give any ideas on how to get notified when combo finished loading? 
Im a newbie with front end development, and about to give up on this!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say is there an Observer-like pattern, do you mean within jQuery?

Comment: Yes, or within this plugin, i dont have a deep knowledge on jquery. Thanks for answering.

Comment: What plugin are you referring to, if not jQuery? Also, if you don't have a deep knowledge 'on' jQuery I would suggest using vanilla JavaScript for your solution until you get a better grasp on front end development

Comment: I mean this plugin: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ .